# What is the remainder on division of $z^{400} + z^{303} + 1$ by $z^4-1$?

Tags: polynomials

I am asked to determine the remainder when the polynomial $f(z)=z^{400}+z^{303}+1$ is divided by the polynomial $g(z)=z^4-1$.

I expressed f as $f(z) = h(z)(z^4-1) + r(z)$ where $r(z)$ is a polynomial

Realising that $z^4-1 = (z^2-1)(z^2+1) = (z-1)(z+1)(z^2+1)$, I expressed f as

$f(z) = h(z)(z-1)(z+1)(z^2+1) + r(z)$

I also wrote f as $f(z) = q(z)(z-1) + 3$, since $f(1)=3$, and q is some polynomial.

So I had $f(z)= q(z)(z-1) + 3 = h(z)(z-1)(z+1)(z^2+1) + r(z)$

Hence, for some constant k, $q(z)=h(z)(z+1)(z^2+1) + k$

We know $f(-1) = 1$

From $f(z) = q(z)(z-1) + 3$, we have $f(-1)=q(-1)(-2) + 3 = 1$, which implies
$q(-1) = 1$.

Then $q(-1)=h(-1)(0) + k = 1$. Thus, $k=1$

We then have $q(z)=h(z)(z+1)(z^2+1) + 1$, and from this, we have
$f(z)= q(z)(z-1) + 3 = (h(z)(z+1)(z^2+1) + 1)(z-1) + 3$
Which simplifies to $f(z) = h(z)(z^4-1) + z+2$

And gives $r(z) =z+2$.

But I am given the answer is $r(z) = z^3+ 2$. What is going wrong here? Can I use modular arithmetic instead? How?

Comment: To get $z^{400}$, use `z^{400}`. [How to format mathematics on this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I'm going to assume you mean $z^{400}$?

Comment: I fixed it, thanks MJD

Comment: @2good4this You should enclose all math in `$...$` to greatly improve readability.

Comment: When you have a formula like `f(z) = h(z)(z^4-1) + r(z)` , do not put the `$` signs around just the `z^4` term; it looks bad and is hard to read: f(z) = h(z)($z^4$-1) + r(z).  Put the `$` signs around the whole formula `$f(z) = h(z)(z^4-1) + r(z) $` to obtain $f(z) = h(z)(z^4-1) + r(z) $.  This is easier for you to type and easier for us to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we can write $f(z)=h(z)(z^4-1)+r(z)$ where $r(z)$ is a polynomial of degree at most three (one less than the degree of $z^4-1$).

An unknown polynomial of degree $3$ has four coefficients to be determined. If we successively use $z=1, z=-1, z=i, z=-i$ - the four roots of $z^4-1$ the term involving $h(z)$ will vanish.

This gives us $f(1)=r(1)=3$, $f(-1)=r(-1)=1$, $f(i)=r(i)=2-i$, $f(-i)=r(-i)=2+i$

If $r(z)=az^3+bz^2+cz+d$ we have $$a+b+c+d=3$$$$-a+b-c+d=1$$

From which we obtain $b+d=2$ and $a+c=1$

Also $$-ai-b+ci+d=2-i$$ From which $-b+d=2$ so $b=0, d=2$ and $-a+c=-1$ so that $a=1, c=0$

$$r(z)=z^3+2$$

---

Where you seem to have gone wrong is when you get to

$$f(z)=q(z)(z-1)+3=h(z)(z-1)(z+1)(z^2+1)+r(z)$$

From this you can conclude that $(z-1)\left(q(z)-h(z)(z+1)(z^2+1)\right)=r(z)-3$ but that does not mean that the term in large brackets is a constant. It is that assumption which puts you off track.

Comment: @2good4this That's OK - i've put a note to say where I think your mistake is. Also I like Mario G's answer a lot.

Comment: I am not sure I get your note. I thought that the two expressions of f(z) I wrote above were equivalent, of course depending on what the polynomials q,h and r are. In what way have I assumed that the term in large brackets is constant? Does that term not depend on r(z)?

Comment: @2good4this You say in your question "Hence, for some constant $k, q(z)=h(z)(z+1)(z^2+1)+k$". $k$ is therefore equal to what I have put in my large(r) brackets.

Comment: I see you are right. k is not necessarily constant. That's where I veered off track.

Comment: I was wondering, the approach you used here only works because we knew what the polynomial f(z) was. In the case that f was not specified,which is what I keep encountering in my assignments, how would we approach the same problem, if at all we could?

Comment: @2good4this If you don't know anything about a polynomial it is hard to say anything about its remainder. Why don't you post one of your questions as another question on this site and explain what is difficult about it.

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

Since
\begin{align*}
z^{400}+z^{303}+1&=z^{400}-1+(z^{300}-1)z^3 +z^3+2 \\
&=(z^4-1)(z^{396}+z^{392}+\ldots +1)+(z^4-1)(z^{296}+z^{292}+\ldots +1)z^3+z^3+2\\
\end{align*}
It follows that $z^3+2$ is the asked remainder.